# App Center Push with Google Sign In on React Native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, google-signin, visual-studio-app-center

I've been trying to integrate Microsoft App Center Push with React Native on Android. I am following the official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/react-native-android). I have also used the '[react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin)' module for google login.

The problem is that when using these 2 together, the notifications only come through when the app is in the foreground. I have narrowed down the issue to the **com.google.gms.google-services** gradle plugin (required by the google sign in module) which seems to add the following BroadcastReceiver and Service to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="se.crossplatform.parkeraapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

These seem to override the following BroadcastReceiver and Service added to the AndroidManifest.xml by the App center Push module

```
<receiver android:name="com.microsoft.appcenter.push.PushReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="se.crossplatform.parkeraapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.microsoft.appcenter.push.TokenService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I am at a loss on how to solve this

Comment: Can you enable verbose logging in Java (not JS) code as explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/other-apis/react-native#adjust-the-log-level then create a ticket using blue chat button on https://appcenter.ms and share the logs when app starts and logs when push is sent and should be received?

Comment: I fixed it by explicitly adding firebase core and messaging to my gradle dependencies. I thought of doing this last, because AppCenter documentation claims that its no longer dependent on Firebase. @GuillaumePerrot

Comment: If you are using Firebase in your app you indeed need explicit dependencies like you did as our SDK has no dependency anymore in the libraries manifest.